# Difficulty understanding an integration identity

Tags: integration, calculus

in reading a textbook recently I've come across an identity that I can't derive, even though it looks like it should be easy:

$$ \lim _{x_0 \to \infty} \int d^3\vec{x}~-~  \lim _{x_0 \to -\infty} \int d^3\vec{x} ~\equiv~ \int d^4x \frac{\partial}{\partial x_0} ,
$$

where as usual $(x_0, \vec{x})$ is a point in space-time.

Any hints/help in deriving this is appreciated.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Thanks for the help! Particularly the edit - I was mostly confused by the notation.

Comment: Are these supposed to be considered as operators? (i.e., essentially, should there be some function of $(x_0, \vec{x})$ under the integral signs here, with appropriate properties to make the integrals convergent?)